# Find Pre-defined Combinations Between Two Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, intersection

I have one object and one array:

```
"catalog" : {
    "thing" : {
         "required_components" : [ "a", "d" ]
    },
    "gadget" : {
        "required_components" : [ "e", "e" ]
    },
    "device" : {
        "required_components" : [ "d", "e" ]
    },
   "entity" : {
        "required_components" : [ "a", "a" ]
    }
}

myComponents = ["a", "d", "c", "a", "e"]
```

I'd like to create an array of possible catalog items given the components listed in `myComponents`.

I'm currently iterating over `catalog` and using `.filter()` to get the intersection of `myComponents` and `required_components`:

```
console.log(requiredComponents.filter(x => myComponents.includes(x))) //Outputs ["a", "d"]
```

Then if `requiredComponents.filter(x => myComponents.includes(x)).length == 2`, I push the currently iterated upon catalog item to an array.

But this seems clunky and it produces some undesirable and unexpected results.

First, because I'm doing it within a loop, it pushes multiple duplicate items to the array. I could overcome this with more clunky code.

Second, I end up with catalog items I do not have the components for. For example, if I have `["a", "a"]` I'll somehow end up with `thing` in my output array. Maybe this has something to do with the fact that it's happening within a loop as well.

In any case, there must be a much cleaner way to do this.

```js
let catalog = [["a", "d"],["e", "e"], ["d","e"], ["a", "a"]];
let myComponents = ["a", "d", "c", "a"];
let possibleComponents = [];

catalog.forEach(item => {
  possibleComponents.push(item.filter(x => myComponents.includes(x)));
});
console.log(possibleComponents);
```

Comment: What is `requiredComponents`?  Please make an [mcve] of the issue so we can see it in action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to come from the duplicates when comparing arrays.

Here's a short prototype with lodash:

```js
import _ from 'lodash'

// Check if subset is included in superset (respecting duplicates).
const isSubset = (subset, superset) => {
  const subsetCount = _.countBy(subset)
  const supersetCount = _.countBy(superset)

  return _.every(subsetCount, (count, value) => supersetCount[value] >= count)
}

// Filter all catalog items, that could be build by myComponents
const matches = _.pickBy(catalog, ({required_components}, thing) => isSubset(required_components, myComponents))

// Get only the names of the catalog items
const names = _.keys(matches)
```